# Observe @each and get updated item

Tags: ember.js

I'm observing a controller property (an object) in my view with `@each`. Every time, `@each` changes, I want to know, **which** item has changed.

Is there a way to find it out?

```
Docket.OrganizationView = Ember.View.extend({

  chartObserver: function() {

    console.log(THE_ITEM_OF_CHARTDATA_THAT_HAS_CHANGED)

  }.observes('controller.chartData.@each')

});
```

Comment: i doubt you can get it. lets see. Observers can actually initiated by many ways. Since its chart data i suggest you to redraw whole chart.

Comment: The problem is, that there are 5 charts and I don't want to redraw 5 charts even if only one dataset has changed. `@each` includes the data for the different charts. I will store them in different properties for the moment, but I think the question is interesting anyway.

Comment: i had same problem sometime back...i wasn't able to find solution..what i did was added key in that data object itself....yea question is very interesting, would be nice if there is solution for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a [ArrayComputed](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_arrayComputed) property in your controller as this [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yiyak/1/edit).

> [ArrayComputed](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_arrayComputed): Creates a computed property which operates on
>   dependent arrays and is updated with "one at a time" semantics.

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  changedContent: Ember.arrayComputed("content.@each.name", {

    addedItem: function(array, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
      array.clear();
      array.pushObject(item);
      return array;
    },
    removedItem: function(array, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {

      array.clear();
      array.pushObject(item);
       return array;

    }
  }),

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`observesBefore`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Function.html#method_observesBefore) call to store the array before it changes, so that you can compare it with the array after the change:

```
Docket.OrganizationView = Ember.View.extend({
  chartDataWillChange: function() {
    this._oldChartData = this.get('controller.chartData').slice(0);
  }.observesBefore('controller.chartData.@each')

  chartDataDidChange: function() {
    var oldChartData = this._oldChartData;
    var newChartData = this.get('controller.chartData');

    // Compare the contents of the two arrays
    // to find out what has changed
    var addedItems = newChartData.filter(function(item) {
      return !oldChartData.contains(item);
    });
    var removedItems = oldChartData.filter(function(item) {
      return !newChartData.contains(item);
    });
  }.observes('controller.chartData.@each')
});
```